# List row and count from another tables in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following tables:

**___Support**

```
SUP_Id | SUP_Message
-------+------------
1      | Lorem...
2      | Ipsum...
```

**___SupportMessage**

```
SUM_Id | SUM_TicketId
-------|-------------
60     | 1
61     | 1
62     | 1
63     | 1
64     | 2
65     | 2
```

I need to list all the tickets contained in `___Support` and count the ticket messages (stored in `___SupportMessages`) I have for each ticket.

I should have :

- 4 messages for ticket # 1
- 2 messages for ticket # 2

My actual try is the following:

```
SELECT *,
    COUNT(
        SELECT *
        FROM ___SupportMessages 
        WHERE ___SupportMessages.SUM_TicketId = ___Support.SUP_Id
) 
FROM ___Support
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close.  Put the `count()` in the `select`:

```
SELECT s.*,
      (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM ___SupportMessages sm
       WHERE sm .SUM_TicketId = s.SUP_Id
      ) 
FROM ___Support s
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by below

```
 select count(SUM_Id),SUM_TicketId from ___SupportMessage where SUM_TicketId in (select  
 SUP_Id from ___Support) group by SUM_TicketId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sm.SUP_Message, count(*) as [count]
from ___Support sm
join ___SupportMessage st 
  on sm.SUP_Id = st.SUM_TicketId 
group by sm.SUP_Message
```

Comment: `from SUM_TicketId sm` should be `from ___Support sm` I guess ?